# 2 internet connections for added speed

Tags: networking, internet-connection

I have an ADSL broadband, which comes over LAN (with max speed ~220kb/s). And another connection is using a high-speed internet enabled CDMA phone (with max speed ~300kb/s), where I use USB tethering.

I connected both together and tested on uTorrent. I had supposed that without any special settings or software, both wouldn't work; but it did. I had my ADSL connected and the speed was 220Kb/s, and when I connected my USB tethered phone, speeds increased to 250-300kb/s. I was observing the network activity and my ADSL was being used to it's max speed and rest was by the CDMA phone.

I tried settings like `net.bind_ip` and `net.outgoing_ip` on uTorrent, but same results, my CDMA's internet wasn't being used to it's max speed. What can I do to use both together effectively for higher speeds?

Answer (score 1):

EYou should try [Speedify](http://speedify.com/) or [Connectify Dispatch](http://www.connectify.me/dispatch/). 
Speedify automatically detects and bonds active Internet connections such as WiFi, DSL, Ethernet, and 3G & 4G devices. The more you have the faster you’ll go!

If you want to do it free check [this link](http://www.wikihow.com/Combine-Two-Internet-Connections).

**Combining LANs (wired,wireless or DSL)**

1. Turn everything on, i.e. your computer, modems.
2. Connect them on the relative ports.
3. Dial, or do whatever you need to do to establish internet connection and test each one by one, separately. If all good proceed to the next step.
4. While each one is active and connected navigate to the "Network Devices" folder of your computer. It usually stays under control panel.
   Windows 8 or Windows 8.1: Press Windows+D to navigate to the desktop, and rest is same as windows 7 below.
   For Windows 7 and Vista: Click the network icon on the task bar-> then click "Open Network and Sharing Center". Then click "Change Adapter settings".
   For XP: Click Start > Control Panel.Then on the Control Panel window, double-click Network Connections.
5. Review the window showing all of your network connections. The active connections will be two blue desktops without a red cross sign.
6. Drag and select Active LAN (Wired, Wireless or DSL Modem) connections.
7. Right click on one of the selected-> click "Bridge Connections" . Then wait and a network bridge with different icon will appear. You might have to provide administrative right.
8. Enjoy double speed :)

**Combine All Other Types of Connection**

Power up everything and connect to the required ports. 
Check each connections separately.
Navigate to your network device (adapter) folder.
Right click one network adaptor at a time (out of your active and working adapters (connections)). Change the Interface Id to the same number (say choose 10 for all). Repeat this for each connection.
Click "OK" or "Apply." If neither of these is available click "Close". Don't click "No" or "Cancel".
Disconnect everything. Do a cold reboot (shut down the machine and then power it up again).
Reconnect everything. Enjoy maximized speed :)

Comment: this sort of solution doesn't necessarily add speed, but just designates multiple connections from the same source. For example, a file transfer from one destination will only ever use one of the lines. It may still saturate that line, and leave the other line completely open. But the second request you make, may go to the second line, and therefore still have bandwidth to work with. This is more like load balancing than true bonding. If you want true bonding, it has to be done on both sides - your ISP may be able to provide options for true bonding (something like EoC, or bonded DSL).

Comment: I agree with you but for programs like uTorrent it will definitely work, or for different programs where you can give one network connection to one program and second to the other :)

Comment: I had tried those settings before hand. The speed increase is still the same. And I had tried the software too, they have disabled uTorrent, so no point trying. Any other method?

Answer (score 0):

I tried what @Davidenko said. It works. I speedtested on Ookla and I downloaded from Steam with higher speed. The thing is that at my speedtest my upload speed was the same as before, only from ethernet. Can I fix it somehow? Maybe the speedtest time is too little to draw from the USB tethering?

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.